# How to pass nested list to REST end-point in Python?

Tags: python, list, rest

I have the following list in Python:

```
[['type1', 'type2'], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

and I need to pass it as a parameter to my REST end-point. If I pass it as it is, then the error is thrown because it's a list. If I convert it into a string using `str(mynestedlist)`, then I don't know how to convert it back to the list in the end-point.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not convert it to Json for example?

Comment: @AndrejKesely: Could you please show the right way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: use `json.dumps(lst)` where `lst` is your list. To parse it, use `json.loads()`. Or if you use `requests` module, you can use `json=` parameter and `.json()` method on response.

Comment: @AndrejKesely: Yes, I use `requests`. Not sure I understood correctly what you ment with `json=` and `.json()`?

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `requests` you can do:

```py
lst = [['type1', 'type2'], [], [], [], [], [], []]

response = requests.post(API_URL, json=lst).json() # response is now standard python dictionary/list
```

On the server you get all POST data in form of Json. So you can use `json.loads()` on them. Return a Json data.